# How to automatically add '\n' To paragraph

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, paragraph

I have a long paragraph, I split it using `'\n'` and use it in canvas. I don't want to do the same thing in every paragraph, because I will have too many paragraphs. Is there a way for me to automatically insert the `'\n'` in certain parts of the paragraph?

```py
from tkinter import *

w = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(width = 800, height = 800)
canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0)

paragraph = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur\nadipiscing elit. Nam sollicitudin rhoncus\nipsum. Morbi sed metus sollicitudin, tristique\nsapien vitae, cursus nulla. Mauris vel accumsan\npurus. Vestibulum orci est, euismod non ultricies\nporttitor, blandit at mi. Integer ut lectus congue,\nfinibus magna a, mattis erat. Proin quis egestas\nligula."

canvas.create_text(50, 50, text=paragraph, anchor=NW, font="Times 5 bold")

w.mainloop()
```

Comment: How is the program supposed to know where to insert the newlines?

Comment: Define "certain parts"

Comment: can't you use `Text` widget? or `Message`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `textwrap` module. For the example I unwrapped the paragraph by removing newlines, but you wouldn't do that in cases where text was wrapped manually.

```
from tkinter import*
import textwrap

w=Tk()

canvas =Canvas(width = 800, height = 800)
canvas.place(relx=0,rely=0)

paragraph="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur\nadipiscing elit. Nam sollicitudin rhoncus\nipsum. Morbi sed metus sollicitudin, tristique\nsapien vitae, cursus nulla. Mauris vel accumsan\npurus. Vestibulum orci est, euismod non ultricies\nporttitor, blandit at mi. Integer ut lectus congue,\nfinibus magna a, mattis erat. Proin quis egestas\nligula."

# lazy way to get rid of the newlines for test
paragraph = paragraph.replace("\n", " ")
wrapped = textwrap.fill(paragraph, 40)

canvas.create_text(50,50,text=wrapped,anchor=NW,font="Times 5 bold")

w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

If "certain parts" means a number of words or some lenght, you can write a function do add \n for you based on that.

Comment: poorly written answer, please add code to support it, write the function